# Particle number in lattice field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

Is it even possible to calculate a particle number of some field in lattice field theory? After all, it's implemented in the formalism of imaginary time path integrals, here's no such concepts as particle number operator, creation and annihilation operators. After searching the internet i didn't find anything useful. I'm interested in bosonic fields.

Comment: Being able to jump between different formulations allows one to compute such quantities, as Mike Stone showed. I don't know how to interpret these quantities in the original formulation though. Maybe it can't be done in a useful way.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-express the Euclidean path integral in terms of the trace of powers of a  transfer matrix $T\sim  e^{-H}$, and so re-introduce  all the opertors. For  the (relativistic)   boson field, just as for its continuum version,  there is is no conserved particle number, only the total $U(1)$ charge. This charge is certainly definable as an opertor on the space in which the transfer matrix acts.

Comment: The total U(1) charge is the difference between the number of particles and antiparticles. But many bosons are their own antiparticles, so it only makes sense(in my case) to calculate for charged bosons, such as the W boson.